# Python: os.listdir files are not found

Tags: python, json, file

I recently moved my config files to another folder in my Project. I try to load the like this:

```
CONFIG_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/../config/")    

def load_config():
    configs = {}
    for config in os.listdir(CONFIG_PATH):
        configs[str(config)[0:-12]] = json.load(open(config))
    return configs
```

I'm running the code from

```
D:/.../MyProject/src
```

And the specified `CONFIGPATH` is correctly set to

```
D:/.../MyProject/config
```

Now in that iteration loop, the `open(config)` raises an exception:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.config.json'
```

I can't see why my program can't open a file, which clearly has to exist since it is given out by `os.listdir`. Actually, a `print(config)` in the loop confirms that there is a file with that name. So why won't it open and instead raises a FileNotFoundError?

Do I miss the obvious here? The code worked before I moved the files upwards. I'm working with Pycharm on Windows 7, if that is of any relevance.

Comment: Yes you are missing something obvious. File of that name exists, but you are only passing name of file to `open()` without proper path.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should get into the habit of using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build paths.

Comment: Thank you, I did miss that when refiddling paths etc.

Answer (score 3):

`os.listdir` only return the name of the file, not the complete path.

If you're on 3.5 you can use `os.scandir` where the returned item has a path attribute. If you're not that lucky, you'll have to construct the full path yourself.

It would be: `json.load(open(os.path.join(CONFIG_PATH, config)))` in your case.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it like this. I use 3.4, but the `os.scandir` looks really nice.